# update mongoDB collection using nodejs// throw new TypeError('Update document requires atomic operators');

Tags: node.js, mongodb

so im able to create a collection using nodejs / mongoDB
using this code

```
  // create a collection and inserting the object
     dbo.collection('employees').insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
  //if there is an error throw error message
    if (err) throw err;
  // print out if collection is created
    console.log(colors.green("Collection created ✓"),'\n','\n',companyMotto, '-', 
   subDomain,'\n','\n');
  //close the db
    db.close();
    });
```

im trying to figure out a code to update the collection as a whole if they collection already exists  using this

```
  // create a collection and inserting the object
  dbo.collection('employees').updateOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
  //if there is an error throw error message
    if (err) throw err;
  // print out if collection is updated
    console.log(colors.green("Collection updated ✓"),'\n','\n',companyMotto, '-', 
   subDomain,'\n','\n');
  //close the db
    db.close();
    });
```

but im getting an error "...throw new TypeError('Update document requires atomic operators');"
any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a collection, you should just call `createCollection` instead. `insertOne` is for you to insert a document into a collection and `updateOne` is for you to update a particular document in a collection

`Update document requires atomic operators` means an update operation is not supplied. So mongodb doesn't know how you want the document to be updated. e.g. `$set` to update a value, `$push` to push a value into an array

You can refer to the nodejs doc to see how `updateOne` is supposed to be called.
`updateOne(filter, update, options, callback)`

See:
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#updateOne